# Retrieving Google Reader stats for RSS feed and items

Tags: api, rss, google-reader

I would like to programmatically retrieve Google Reader's feed stats for my own site's RSS feed. In particular, I'd like to get the "liked" count, to incorporate it into scoring feed items.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get stats (such as subscribercount) using the following URL:

http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/details?s=feed/[your feed url here]

You can get likes for your feed items using the following URL ():

http://www.google.com/reader/atom/feed/[your feed url here]

Comment: Thanks! Just what I was looking for! Any idea how I can retrieve this without being logged in? If not, I'll probably be able to figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

you can also connect the list to a KPI web part

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/create-and-publish-key-performance-indicators-kpis-HA010080027.aspx