# Google Reader API Linking reader's User ID to a Google Account

Tags: rss, google-reader

I am developing a web application that heavily utilizes RSS feeds.

I have found you can query Google to get statistics and analytics on your RSS Feed (very useful, if you administer RSS feeds, you should check it out! [Retrieving Google Reader stats for RSS feed and items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635141/retrieving-google-reader-stats-for-rss-feed-and-items))

Now that I have a method to determine a list of Google Reader User Ids that like a feed item, I would like to know how I could use this User Id.

Specifically, is there a way I can link a User Id to a Google Account - if they are logged in through a web interface like Stack Overflow does?

If this is not possible, what public information can be gathered about a particular Google Reader User Id? Is there documentation on this API? (note, I am not looking for Google Reader API, which, from my understanding, allows you to build your own RSS Reader)

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/people/profile?u=14290265284323789574